# Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries .. when using libclang for ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I was able to cross-compile llvm/clang for i386 and i'm trying to use it in my ios app.
Also i was able to add headers and static libs (both libLLVM*.a and libclang*.a) and compile/link the project with no errors.

But when trying to run simple app i'm getting error:

> Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not
>   present on the iPhone: pthread_mutexattr_destroy$UNIX2003 called from
>   function _ZN4llvm3sys9MutexImplC2Eb in image LibClangUsageDemo3.

What can i do in order to fix it?

Is it llvm/clang issue or i'm doing smth wrong?

**Update**: i was able to find error line - `Mutex.cpp`:

```
// Destroy the attributes
errorcode = pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);
assert(errorcode == 0);
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but what is the purpose of cross-compiling for i386?  I'm not aware of any iOS devices on that architecture

Comment: ios simulator is i386

Comment: Does your app work on an actual iOS device, or do you get a similar error there as well?

Comment: it does not work at all since i'm getting this error right at the moment the app starts. i'd like to make it working in ios simulator first